# Laravel 4 and Backbone not playing well together -- JSON improperly formatted

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

I'm trying to return JSON output from a Laravel route.  Here's my route:

```
Route::get('main-contact-count', function() {
    $mc = MainContact::where('flag', '=', '1')->count();
    return Response::json(['count' => $mc]);
});
```

If I look at the response tab in Firebug, I'm getting back:

```
{"count":9}
```

The JSON encoding is missing the square brackets.  This JSON is different than the JSON Laravel returns from a resourceful controller.  It has the square brackets.  Backbone parses it fine.  Backbone doesn't parse the above JSON correctly.  If you look at the length and models when you `console.log` a collection, they're both zero.  You can, however, drill down into the object and you can find a `count` property set to 9.

How do I get the correct JSON out of Laravel?

Just for kicks and giggles, I'm posting my Backbone, in case I'm doing something hinky there:

```
App.Collections.Count = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Count,
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data, options) {
                    // console.log(data.models);
                }
            });
            if (options) {
                this.url = this.url || options.url;
            }
        }
    });

    App.Views.Count = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'span',
        className: 'leadCount',
        template: _.template($('#contactCount').html()),
        initialize: function() {

        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
```

And in my route:

```
var mc = new (App.Collections.Count.extend({ url: 'main-contact-count' }))();
var mcv = new (App.Views.Count.extend({ collection: mc }))();
```

Comment: The json returned by laravel is correct , [] in php is not [] in javascript. in your case Laravel is right to return an object not an array since you have some string keys in your php array. if you want to return an array of objects , return array(array('count' => $mc))

Comment: That gives me a server error.

Comment: it was an exemple you need to return a correct Laravel response. see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON response sent by your service is a single JSON object (`{...}`) Your collection is not able to parse it because it expects an array of JSON objects (`[{...}, {...}]`).

If I've understood your code correctly, `/main-contact-count` is a specialized service whose function is to return and single datum: a count of contacts. If this is the case, `Backbone.Collection` may not be the correct solution. Collections are meant for... well, collections of things.

You should use just a model instead:

```
App.Models.Count = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'main-contact-count'
});

var countModel = new App.Models.Count();
countModel.fetch({success: function(model, resp) {
    var count = model.get('count');
});
```

Or even better, forego Backbone altogether and just fetch the data using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('main-contact-count', function(response) {
    var count = response.count;
});
```

Comment: In your Backbone example, I get count as undefined when I alert it.

Comment: I got it.  I had the JSON call from camus' answer still in my code.  Thanks, Fencliff.  And thanks for telling me about using models instead.  I wondered about that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
return Response::json(array(array('count' => $mc));
```

Comment: I still get an empty array

Comment: where ? from the server or the js backbone code ? even if $mc is null the server response cannot be an empty array in that case.